# Simple Mdi Parent and MdiChild Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three forms 1 is Mdiparent and the other two is simple form (Form1 and Form2).

Parent:

```
var frmForm1 = new Form1{ MdiParent = this};
frmForm1.Show();
```

Form1 :
    var MParent = new Parent();
    var frmForm2 = new Form2{ MdiParent = MParent};
    frmForm2.Show();

My Problem is if i Show Form2 from Form1 it goes outside the MdiParent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the answer.

```
var frmForm2 = new Form2{ MdiParent =This.MParent};
 frmForm2.Show();
```