# winforms - loading different forms in one Main form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So I have a Desktop application which works with a lot of different forms which an user may need. I have a main form with navigation to the different forms but now every new form is loaded in a new window. What is the best approach to implement a functionality that will show only the main form which is in fact just a `toolStrip` with several menus and use the other space to load the other forms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049479/simple-mdi-parent-and-mdichild-winforms

Comment: You can use an MDI form.

Comment: why that? I think you'd better use `MdiParent` and `MdiChild` forms

Comment: Well as you can see I'm fairly new so I don't know what to use, gonna read about MDI, haven't heard it before.

Comment: Are you sure your application works with a lot of different *forms* rather than (compound, custom) *controls*? Customarily, a *form* in Windows Forms *is* a window (no matter whether it's free on the desktop or nested in some parent window, as happens with MDI).

Comment: O. R. Mapper yeah, even though I'm not 100% sure abut the terminology it's a different forms with different functionality, they are even created as forms right now, I just want to show them as described in the post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want to see the different forms. Could you add a simple sketch to your question that shows what your main window is supposed to look like while, say, two forms are loaded, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want an MDI implementation.

You have to set the mainform.IsMdiContainer = true
And the childForm.MdiParent = mainform